# Is there a simple way to style text with gradients?

Tags: colors, css, gradient

it is possible to style a background with gradients like:
`background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc));`

Is there a way to style text with gradients?I've been looking for sth like:
`color-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc));`but wasn't able to find anything simple.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not possible with pure CSS unless you use a image to cover the font:
http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect/
You could use the same technique but use a color to transparent gradient in the overlay element.

here is an example with pure CSS and an additional element: http://jsfiddle.net/Lub7z/

Comment: That was the answer I was afraid of :-) I'll mark it as answered asap.

Answer (score 1):

It IS possible. You just have to combine a background-image with a background-clip: text: See [this most excellent example](http://trentwalton.com/bgclip/) here.

```
background: url(/bgclip/img/paint.png) repeat, white;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
```

Comment: sure but its webkit only atm.